# how to change name variable with another variable R

Tags: r, variables

Hi i want rename variables in R with use another variable.
my problem is use variable.

```r
name1<- 11
name2<- 22
name2<- 33

nameVar<-"name2"
d<-nameVar
```

```r
nameVar<-"name3"
```

then d also will change from 22 to 33

thank you for help !

Comment: You may check `?assign` and `?get`

Comment: Not sure I fully follow, since `d` never has the value 22. However, `d <- get(nameVar)` will assign to `d` the value of `name2` at the time of the call.

Comment: @r2evans i dont know how i can explain it. i get 3 variables v1=11, v2=22, v3=33. and i want make another variable (d<-nameVar). If nameVar<-"v1" then d=11 when nameVar<-v2 then d=22. i want choose value for d with use nameVar

Comment: Okay, did you try `get(nameVar)`? It's an indirect method for getting the value of an object based on a string representing the object's name. As akrun suggested and I demonstrated, read [`?get`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) (and its companion function [`?assign`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html)), *try the code*, and the come back if what it does and I'm suggesting is not what you need.

Comment: @r2evans, yes, for my example working how i want, but another problem is when i try put there column: example : ```r produkt<-"marchew"
produkt2<-gsub(" ", "", paste("m$", produkt))
W<-get(produkt2) #[c$cebula, m$marchew, z$ziemniaki]  ``` I have error: ```c Error in get(produkt2) : object 'm$marchew' not found``` normal if i do: ```r  W<-m$marchew #[c$cebula, m$marchew, z$ziemniaki]``` it working

Comment: `$` and R in general does not work that way, unless you want to go to meta-programming (*highly* discouraged at your stage) and use `eval(parse(text=produkt2))`. Your needs are spiraling up, perhaps the OP is a little over-simplified. I think it may also be good to know why you want to do these operations so indirectly.

Comment: @r2evans i have to make rpres with 3 type of products. And i dont want do this for every products, just change one variable